# No data show in the browser - Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular

I did this service

```
export class TeacherService {
  private url: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  // Teacher - Get a teacher by Id
  getTeacherById(teacherId: number): Observable<ITeacher[]>
  {
    this.url = 'http://localhost:5000/teachers/getteacher/' + teacherId;
    return this.http.get<ITeacher[]>(this.url);
  }
}
```

Then in component, I did

```
export class TeacherComponent implements OnInit {
  teacher: ITeacher[] = [];
  datasource: Observable<ITeacher[]>;
  pSubscribe: Subscription;

  constructor(public teacherService: TeacherService) {
    this.datasource = this.getTeacher();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pSubscribe = this.datasource.subscribe((data: []) => this.teacher = data);
  }

  getTeacher(): Observable<ITeacher[]> {
    const id = 1;
    return this.teacherService.getTeacherById(id);
  }

}
```

In HTML i did

```
<p *ngFor="let item of teacher" >
  {{ item.Name }} - {{item.Salary}} - {{item.Skills}}
</p>
```

No data show and in console it gives me error message "Error trying to diff 'James Lord'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed". James Lord is the name of the teacher but cannot be displayed.

Comment: First, try outputting this.teacher in the console to make sure it is an iterable (do that in the subscribe function).

Comment: What you need `pSubscribe` For? Just call `ngOnInit(): void {
 const id = 1; this.teacherService.getTeacherById(id) .subscribe((data: []) => this.teacher = data);
  }` inside of your ngOnInit

Comment: @Sébastien here is the result Object { id: 1, name: "James Lord", skills: "Programming", salary: 1500 }

Comment: And much better approach would be to use `async` Pipe in your template so you don’t need to take care about subscribing and unsubscribing, have a look over here https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-async-pipe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your data is not iterable. You cannot iterate over literal objects with `*ngFor` by default.

Given this data:

```
{ id: 1, name: "James Lord", skills: "Programming", salary: 1500 }
```

You can either create an array containing all your object's values or use the literal object with the [`keyvalue`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe in the template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of teacher | keyvalue">
    {{ item.value.name}} {{ item.value.salary}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sebastien's answer is good. I have another answer. If you can change API data like this,

```
[{ id: 1, name: "James Lord", skills: "Programming", salary: 1500 } ]
```

No need to edit HTML file.

```
<p *ngFor="let item of teacher" >
  {{ item.Name }} - {{item.Salary}} - {{item.Skills}}
</p>
```